# Mongodb Migration Threshold Controls?

Tags: mongodb, data-migration

I'm seeking a way to control sharded collection migration thresholds in mongodb.  These thresholds are described at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/#sharding-migration-thresholds

What I see in those values is that they have tuned the migration thresholds for roughly 10% of the chunk counts for small numbers of chunks (0-20: 2, 20-80: 4, 80+: 8).  Above that, it's locked at 8 chunks: just 8 chunk counts being different between shard members will trigger a migration activity.

For our collections having high activity rates and large bodies of data, this causes balancing thrash - there is almost always a difference of 8 chunks, all the time.  With high transaction rates on a sharded collection, there are a range of perfectly-acceptable causes of temporary imbalance (which I won't go into here).  When we shut off the balancer, small temporary imbalances are often then corrected organically as activity across the cluster shifts.  With the balancer turned on, by the time it finishes one migration, another (or many in parallel) triggers right away.

With the thresholds locked down like this, our larger collections thrash all the time - consuming IOPS and network bandwidth that we would really like to use in other ways.  These tiny migrations have no practical benefit, either: if we're talking about a large collection, then 8 chunks can be a vanishingly small quantity of data relative to any real workload.  So we're spending a lot of energy moving lots of small snippets around for zero effective benefit.

I would love to find a config file setting that - at a minimum - allows me to redefine those values.  Even better would be to force a fractional policy, like 10% of the  number of chunks in the collection.  I don't see any controls of this type in the mongo documentation, but could be missing it.

Failing that, I'll have to spin up on the code and retool it myself to build from source, so I'm hoping someone has already solved this and I just can't see where to control it.  Thanks in advance!